# Web services and transactions

Tags: java, php, web-services, transactions

I have a client application which needs to communicate via SOAP calls with a second application on a web server. Some of the operations must be atomic, and most of the include web service calls.

I have read about Web Services Transactions (IBM), but could not locate implementations, road-maps, or other hands-on material on this topic.

Should i consider two-phase commit or other distributed protocols for transactions or are there other ways (methodologies) for achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have read about Web Services
>   Transactions (IBM)

It's not just IBM. The 1.0 standard was IBM, IONA, Microsoft and assorted others. 1.1 was IBM, IONA and JBoss.

> but could not
>   locate implementations, road-maps, or
>   other hands-on material on this topic.

*cough*google*cough*

Websphere:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/cjta_wstran.html

JBoss:
http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Transactions_Development_Guide/pt03.html

glassfish:
http://metro.java.net/guide/Using_Web_Services_Atomic_Transactions.html

> Should i consider two-phase commit or
>   other distributed protocols for
>   transactions or are there other ways
>   (methodologies) for achieving this?

"The locking model used by two phase commit transactions is really only suitable for short lived transactions in the same domain of control. If your services run in the same company datacenter you'll probably get away with it. For wider distribution, be it geographical or administrative, you probably want to look at WS-BA, a web service transactions protocol specifically designed for such use."

(That's from [Transaction rollback and web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434950/transaction-rollback-and-web-services) BTW, although you could also have found [Transaction options over Web Service calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464346/transaction-options-over-web-service-calls) without too much trouble)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. and the (*coughing*) google suggestions :) I forgot to mention that on the server-side PHP will be used. So JBoss, Websphere or other applications servers are out of equation. Thanks again for the reply and the info.